# Warn me when I open new pages and when I’m staying too long on the same page

Tags: firefox, time-management

I want Firefox to show me some kind of message each time I open a new link.

It would also be great if some message could pop-up/flash if I'm on an open tab for more than *X* minutes.

My purpose is productivity reminder e.g. "*Are you sure you want to visit this website?*", but different people may have different aims for wanting this feature.

Comment: Do you want to write something of why you have opened a particular link?

Comment: @BarathVutukuri not exactly. I personally want a custom message shown to me when I click.

Comment: @user13107: Do you want to have to *confirm* this message? E.g., with "Okay" and "Cancel", and pressing cancel prevents loading the page?

Comment: @unor yes! that's right.